# Timber - next/prev post from same category

Tags: post, categories, timber

I'm trying to get next/prev post link from same category in WP Timber, but with no luck.

I've already tryed:

```
{{ post.prev.link }}
```

And it's working like a charm - except it does not show items from same category, just the next post.

I've also tryed:

```
{{ function('next_post_link', '%link', 'Next in category', TRUE) }}
```

But it is not working at all - not showing enything.
When i use it without arguments like this:

```
{{ function('next_post_link') }}
```

It is working but again showing only next post but not in same category.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with

```
post.next('category').link
```

and

```
post.prev('category').link
```

while replacing `category` changes your taxonomy in which the posts are connected.

The reference (https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#next) is pretty confusing here; in order to work, the parameter needs to be the slug of the taxonomy you want to remain in.

Internally, timber uses https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post - so if you still have problems, try this method first to make sure wordpress is working as expected.